# Как получить содержимое вложенного словаря?

Tags: python-3.x

Балуюсь с питоном и не могу понять почему не получается выдернуть содержимое вложенного словаря?
Задача такая: Python 3.7 нужно присвоить переменной *foo* содержимое вложенного словаря *х* без использования сторонних библиотек...

### **Код:**

```
parsed_data = []
x = []
y = []


for i in range(5):
    a = 'category_title'
    b = 'category_slug'
    x.append({
        'cat_title': a,
        'cat_slug': b,
    })

for z in range(10):
    a = 'product_title'
    b = 'product_article'
    c = 'product_description'
    y.append({
        'prod_title': a,
        'prod_article': b,
        'prod_description': c,
    })

parsed_data.append({
    'categories': x,
    'products': y,
})

foo = parsed_data['categories']

print(foo)
```

---

### **Traceback**

```
foo = parsed_data['categories']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Ну текст ошибки-то читайте!

Comment: @Эникейщик Серьезно? Я понимаю что там написано, и понимаю что не могу передать строку, я не понимаю каким образом все-таки можно решить такую задачку... Если переписать код без циклов, то все прекрасно работает, но циклы должны остаться...

Comment: Нет, не понимаете ;) Там написано, что у вас список, а вы хотите, чтобы у вас был словарь. Нужно ``parsed_data = {}`` и потом еще немного подкорректировать.

Comment: @Эникейщик У словаря нет метода .append

Comment: И поэтому вы решили использовать список вместо словаря, хотя вам нужен словарь? :D Кэп говорит, что у словаря есть другой метод. "_и потом еще немного подкорректировать_" не зря написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что Вы пытаетесь использовать список как словарь. Если Вам нужен словарь, то и используйте его.

Вот пример:

```py
parsed_data = {}                 # <----- {} вместо []
x = []
y = []


for i in range(5):
    a = 'category_title'
    b = 'category_slug'
    x.append({
        'cat_title': a,
        'cat_slug': b,
    })

for z in range(10):
    a = 'product_title'
    b = 'product_article'
    c = 'product_description'
    y.append({
        'prod_title': a,
        'prod_article': b,
        'prod_description': c,
    })

parsed_data.update({             # <----- update() вместо append()
    'categories': x,
    'products': y,
})

foo = parsed_data['categories']

print(foo)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно )))